# C/C++ project compiles with Xcode but not with gcc/g++

Tags: c++, c, xcode, gcc

When compiling a little C or C++ project in terminal using gcc, g++ or make, I get these kind of errors:

```
/tmp/ccG1caGi.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `display_menu'
main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `get_input'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.c:

```
#include "menu.h"

int main()
{
        display_menu();
        get_input();

        return 0;
}
```

menu.h:

```
void display_menu();
int get_input();
```

However with Xcode I get no errors or warnings.

What could be the issue here? It's seems it's like this when I include files.

Comment: how are you calling the compiler exactly?

Comment: gcc main.c, or make main, etc.

Comment: XCode does the linking part for you. When in terminal, you need compile and link the files that implement the functions yourself.

Comment: where is defined the display_menu() function? and also the get_input() function?

Comment: It's defined in the included header file.

Comment: Where is your file `menu.h`? You maybe should add a `-I/my/path/to/menu.h/` or something like that.

Comment: All files are in the same dir.

Comment: Can you show use this file? and maybe the `C` file also? And the `gcc` command you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, gcc is complaining that it doesn't know where `display_menu` and `get_input` are, what they are doing or how to link them in, and rightly so.

You probably have more sourcefiles, where those functions are defined (`menu.c`, perhaps?).  If so, add them to your compile instruction:

```
gcc main.c menu.c
```

Alternatively, just compile into an object (waiting for the functions later) with the `-c` flag.  This will not make an executable, but will make an object file that awaits final compilation with

```
gcc main.c -c     # Make the main.o object
gcc menu.c main.o # Link the main.o object with a compiled menu.c
```

into a final executable.

Xcode, in all likelihood, knows all about all your source files, and is happy to put them all together in its compilation step.  If you are doing it manually, you have to do a little more work yourself.  Its not when you include files (h files, that is) but when you have multi-file sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a basic `Makefile`:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-W -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SRC= $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ= $(SRC:.c=.o)

all: myexec

myexec: $(OBJ)
    @$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o
```